# Regex matching whitespace and accented characters

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I want to validate a name-string. It can contain normal uppper/lowercase characters like A-Z, a-z, as well as spaces. But names can also have accented characters like `é` and `Ä`, `Ö`, `Ü` etc. So how do I allow accented characters without allowing non-name characters like `/` and `&`.

I've tried with:

`let checkValue = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(value);`

But this doesn't match whitespace and accented characters.

Comment: Maybe you want to just check for *blacklisted* chars? It might turn out easier. Else, I'd rather use an XRegExp library and use something like `^[\p{L}\s]+$` to match strings having whitespaces or letters from the majority of languages (without diacritics though). See https://jsfiddle.net/zv6tmtgy/1/

Comment: thanks for the idea .. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Certainly you may just use a regex from that library in your code to avoid referencing the whole lib, but it will still be a long regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match by unicode range (for unicode values, take a look at [this table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)). Try something like this:

```
[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F\s]+
```

**Explanation:**

1. `a-zA-Z` matches that range of lower and uppercase characters.
2. `\u00C0-\u017F` matches a chunk of accented characters.
3. `\s` matches whitespace.

```js
let nameToCheck = "Lómöwen Thrél"
let checkValue = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F\s]+$/.test(nameToCheck);

document.write(checkValue ? "valid name" : "invalid name");
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you want to match russian characters, change the unicode ranges (just add them to the expression).

Comment: I do not need to add them anywhere, it is your answer. Right now, it is not helpful since it does not meet OP requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the OP is not asking about non-latin characters.

Comment: See the question: *like `é` and `Ä`, `Ö`, `Ü` **etc***.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay, my point is that the OP is not trying to match Russian names but simply accented characters and there's no point in arguing about what is implied by "etc." let the OP just accept a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

I come from Viet Nam and I had same problem. But it's with `â, ê, ô, ơ...` instead of `Ä, Ö, Ü`. There are no way to use regex in that case correctly (but `.+`).

Here is the easiest way I've done:

```
/^[\w\sÄÖÜ]+$/.test(value);
```

Note: `\w` returns true for `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` but white space `\s`

Comment: [Same as below/above](https://regex101.com/r/aP3oV4/1), does not work with maaaany names.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Then, you need add that characters to the regex. The regex doesn't contain characters `ик`

Comment: @HappyCoding the problem with this solution is that you have to manually include every character you want to allow. It is better to use ranges (or your expression rapidly becomes unmanageable).

Comment: @jcuenod ya. I understand. So, that's the reason I said `Here is the easiest way`. Also, it seems like shorter than `\u00C0-\u017F`?

Comment: @HappyCoding but it doesn't work on unknown names... it's a way of matching your test names but doesn't work in the real world.

Comment: @jcuenod I don't argree. If you want to match any name, you must classify the types of that name first. For example: American name is different from Russian name and Vietnamese name. So, detecting unknown name, I think it's: `.+` (any name)

Comment: @HappyCoding: This `.+` leads to what I already commented: a *blacklisting* approach might turn out the cheapest.

Comment: @HappyCoding I agree with you but type of name is not "can have a Ä, Ö or Ü" it's "can have an accent". Type of name is a generic description. Your solution is what should be used if you're trying to match something specific not something generic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew detecting blacklisted characters is a bad idea because you have to come up with all the possible blacklisted characters - in principle it's preferable to accept what is valid than to reject what is invalid because you are making conscious decisions about all data that is coming in so you should be conscious of the edge cases.

Comment: That is why I suggested using an XRegExp library.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fair enough, and to be honest, I think it's a good solution that you should post as an answer rather than just a comment. I would upvote it.